# Bash who, grep problems

Tags: bash, shell-script

Hi I have a problem with bash. I need a "script, which is working in the background and with sleep 60 will check if a person, which login was added as a parameter, is working on the serwer. When the person will log in, should get a "hello" sign, and a sign about this person turning online."
Sorry, translating excercises is little bit difficult for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
who | cut -d " " -f1 | grep $1> /dev/null
z=$?
until [ $z -eq 0 ] ; do
sleep 10
who | cut -d " " -f1 | grep $1> /dev/null
z=$?
done
echo "hello $1" | write $1
```

I've tried to run it on my PC not on my school server. Is it possible? This is what i got back:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: How did you run the script? My guess is that you omitted the parameter, so that $1 is empty. In addition, a few suggestions for improvement: `grep -q` is "quiet", i.e. doesn't output anything. This is prettier than redirection to /dev/null. Also, you can put the who|cut|grep pipeline directly after the `until`, which removes the need for `z` and for launching the pipeline outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then echo Missing user name; exit 1
elif ! grep -q $1 /etc/passwd
then echo No such user: $1; exit 2
fi

until who | cut -d " " -f1 | grep -q $1
do sleep 10
done
echo "hello $1" | write $1
```

First, I added a check whether a valid user name is present.

The `until` keyword expects a *pipeline*, which can be the `test` program, also known as `[`. This is what you used. However, I just used the `who|cut|grep` pipeline. When its exit status is 0, the loop stops. When it is non-zero, the loop continues.

The other, rather minor change is the addition of `-q`. In my personal opinion, it is a nicer way of obtaining the same result as redirection to /dev/null.